# Updating a submodule when multiple git accounts are configured

Tags: git, github

I have two git identities, one is a personal one and the other is for my employer.

My work project uses a submodule and although I can clone the main repo fine, I am not able to update the submodule. What do I need to configure so the submodule can also be updated locally without getting the following error?

```
Fetching origin
From github.com:/work_domain/work_submodule
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I have 2 sets of id_rsa keys in my ~/.ssh directory:

```
id_rsa.pub <= personal ssh key
id_rsa_work.pub <= work ssh key
```

~/.ssh/config file:

```
#work acccount
Host github-work
  HostName github.com
  User git (corrected with info from answers)
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ida_rsa_work

#personal account
Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  Identity ~/.ssh/ida_rsa
```

When I initially cloned my work repo successfully, I used the adjusted host mapping:

```
git clone git@github-work:work_domain/repo_name.git
```

instead of what I normally use when at work:

```
git clone git@github.com:work_domain/repo_name.git
```

Within the work project repo, the .gitmodules file of course has the official mapping:

```
[submodule "work_submodule"]
        path = work_submodule
        url = git@github.com:/work_domain/work_submodule.git
```

Per suggestion below, I updated the .gitmodules attribute to be:

```
[submodule "work_submodule"]
        path = work_submodule
        url = git@github-work:/work_domain/work_submodule.git
```

But still can't update the submodule locally.

Comment: github ssh access always happens with "git" as username -- "work-username" in your ssh config file is thus wrong

Comment: you can change the actual remote of the submodule in .git/config. This will not be pushed or anything but only affect your local repo.

Comment: Updated question with suggestions and latest error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To guard against the possibility of accidentally committing your private URL for the submodule to the repository** (which is dependent on your `.ssh/config`), you should instead edit the url in `.git/ssh`

---

Editing the URL in `.gitmodules` file to use **github-work** is one way of doing it. However since that's a file part of the project, it might be committed by mistake.

Instead as @Chronical mentioned in a comment. To only change the local settings for your particular checkout, you should instead change the URL in `.git/config`

```
url = github-work:/work_domain/work_submodule.git
```

By changing it there instead of in `.gitmodules` you can get rid of the extra step to cleanup stuff that accidentally used the incorrect URL

Note that if you do `git submodule sync` the URL you edit in `.git/config` is overwritten with the one in `.gitmodules`

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have a ~/.ssh/config, it is to be able to use different public/private keys, which means your ssh url should use said config file:

```
 url = github-work:/work_domain/work_submodule.git
 # or
 url = github-personal:/work_domain/work_submodule.git
```

The all point of the config file is to use different keys, *and* to *not* have to mention the user, the port number, the server name and so on.
'`github-work`' and '`github-personal`' are entry keys in that config file, they are not server names.

Second, after modifying the url in the `.gitmodules` file, don't forget to do:

- completely remove your submodule content if it was already loaded from the previous address:

```
rm -Rf work_domain/work_submodule ; git checkout -- work_domain/work_submodule
```

- update again that submodule:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update work_submodule
```

See also, with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020) "[Git submodule url changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364554/6309)" and the new command:

```
git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was that I had remnants from the previous update attempts. Cleaning all of the files did the trick.