# Git submodule url changed

Tags: git, url

I have a Git project which has a submodule. The url of the submodule was recently changed. I have changed the `.gitmodules` and config file to point to the new url. Should I commit the `.gitmodules` file so that the next time I checkout my project and do  `git submodule update --init --recursive` I won't get an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing remote repository for a git submodule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule)

Comment: I read that. Nobody speaks about how and what files  one has to commit.

Comment: "You should just be able to edit the `.gitmodules` file to update the URL and then run `git submodule sync` to reflect that change to the superproject and your working copy." If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify the question and explain what exactly the problem is.

Comment: What steps have to be followed after this? Should I commit the changes done to .gitmodule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, after editing `.gitmodules`, you should commit and push those changes, so the change becomes available to everyone. Otherwise, only your local submodule would point to the new URL and everyone else would still the old URL.

However, you don't need to commit to change the URL locally, `git` will also switch to the new URL if you haven't committed the change.

Answer (score 20):

> Nobody speaks about how and what files one has to commit

No need to change a file, sync/commit: this is now done for you in one new command.

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "`git submodule`" learned a subcommand "**`set-url`**".

See [commit 26b0610](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b061007c1259ed4692554994961dd26874e63e) (29 Oct 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 99c4ff1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99c4ff1bdabc2122a7c6a2b8df87acdd0c2dd18f), 10 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b061007c1259ed4692554994961dd26874e63e): teach set-url subcommand
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>
>
> Currently, in the event that a submodule's upstream URL changes, users have to manually alter the URL in the `.gitmodules` file then run [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) `sync`.
>   Let's make that process easier.
>
> Teach submodule the `set-url` subcommand which will automatically change the `submodule.$name.url` property in the `.gitmodules` file and then run [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) `sync` to complete the process.

The [`git submodule` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b061007c1259ed4692554994961dd26874e63e#diff-49172936faee6fd343976dd3054ba007R184-R188) now includes:

> ```
> set-url [--] <path> <newurl>:
> ```
>
> Sets the URL of the specified submodule to `<newurl>`.
>   Then, it will automatically synchronize the submodule's new remote URL configuration.