# Git Update Path Setting In .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'd like to update the path of a submodule on a local branch and then push those changes. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

### Git 2.25+ (Q1 2020)

See "[Git submodule url changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364554/6309)" and the new command

```
git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>
```

---

### Git 2.24 and before

You need to change the config of the `.gitmodules` file:

```
git config --file=.gitmodules submodule."SubmoduleName".path new/Root/Folder
```

Then re-sync:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

Finally, add, commit and push (from the parent repo)