# GitHub Submodule - Point to External BUT Change 1 File

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, hugo

I'm using this theme in my Hugo site:
https://github.com/panr/hugo-theme-terminal

I've done a git clone for it and then setup submodules to point to the URL for it. That all works. However, I'm changing one of the files in the theme. Is there a way for me to still do submodules and point to the URL of this repo, BUT use the 1 modified file I have locallY?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to fork the theme repository.

That way, you can:

- modify a file, and push it to tour fork
- add the original theme repo as an [upstream remote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309), and fetch from it, to check if you need to update your local fork.
  See "[Pull new updates from original GitHub repository into forked GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)"

Note: since the latest Git 2.25 release, it is easier to change the submodule url.
See "[Git submodule url changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364554/6309)"

```
git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>
```

As I explain in "[How to make an existing submodule track a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)", you can make that submodule follow `master` with:

```
git submodule set-branch --branch master -- path
```

(using [Git 2.22+, Q2 2019](http://git%20submodule%20set-branch%20--branch%20aBranch%20--))

Comment: Thanks. If there are updates in the original, how can I make sure the one file I've modified doesn't get overwritten when syncing?

Comment: @user3498593 because, as describe in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository/3903835#3903835, you will be doing a rebase, which means you will replay your modification on top of the updated upstream Hugo them repo.

Comment: Think I got it. Right now there are no updates to the upstream repo, so I can't really test that. But I modified the file in my fork and pushed the change to it. So when there is a modification in the upstream repo I should be able to fetch upstream and then do a rebase to re-apply my changed file correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. That will involve a force push (git push --force) to your fork, but since you are the only one working on it, that is OK.

Comment: I reference my fork URL in my .gitsubmodules file. The problem is that it appears to be using a non-master branch when referencing the submodule. I've been pushing my changes to the fork to master. Why is it referencing it by another branch the the original author used?

Comment: I added `branch = master` in my `.gitsubmodules` file and that seems to have corrected it. Is that the proper way to do it?

Comment: @user3498593 That should work, but I have edited the answer with the proper command to add a branch for a submodule to follow.